# Prove that $Ann(Ann^{*}(U))=U$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I want to prove the following proposition:

"For any subspace $U$ of $V$, $Ann(Ann^{*}(U))=U$. "

In this context $Ann^{*}(U)=\left \{ w^{*} \in V^{*} : w^{*}(u)=0 \ for \ every \  u\in U\right \},$ and $Ann(U^{*})$ where $U^{*}$ is a subspace of $V^{*}$ is defined by $Ann(U^{*})= \left \{ v \in V : w^{*}(v)=0 \ for \ every \ w^{*} \in U^{*} \right \}$

Here is my approach:

Clearly, $U\subseteq Ann(Ann^{*}(U))$. So we have to prove that $Ann(Ann^{*}(U)) \subseteq U$. Let $\left \{ u_1, u_2, \cdots  \right \}$ be a basis for $U$ and let extend it to $\left \{ u_1, u_2, \cdots  \right \}\cup \left \{ v_1, v_2, \cdots  \right \}$ a basis of $V$. Let $v\in Ann(Ann^{*}(U))$. Then we have that $w^{*}(v)=0$ for all $w^{*} \in Ann^{*}(U)$. We have that there is sequences of finite support $c_i$ and $d_m$ such that $$v=\sum c_iu_i + d_mv_m.$$ Therefore, we have that $$0=\sum c_iw^{*}(u_i)+d_mw^{*}(v_m)=\sum d_mw^{*}(v_m),$$ for all $w^{*} \in Ann^{*}(U).$ Now, choose let $w^{*}(u_i)=0$ for all $i$ and let $w^{*}(v_m)=v_m$ for all $m$. Clearly, $w^{*}$ is a defines a linear transformation such that $w^{*} \in Ann^{*}(U)$ and $$0=\sum d_mw^{*}(v_m)=\sum d_mv_m.$$ Which implies that $d_m=0$ since $\left ( v_m \right )_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a basis for the complement of $U$. Therefore, $v \in U.$

Is my proof correct? I am not sure since I feel that the proof is very short compared to the demonstrations of the other propositions. In particular, I am not sure that my proof of $v \in U$ is correct. Any comments or help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is the definition of $\mathrm{Ann}^{*}\left( U \right)$?

Comment: @fusheng I have edited the question with the definition :)

Comment: Is $V$ finite dimensional ?

Comment: Not necessarily

Comment: Let  $V$ be a Hilbert space, then the right hand of the equation  is  a  closed subspace, $U$ is not necessarily a closed subspace.

Comment: If you choose $V$ to be a Hilbert space and $U$  to be a closed subspace, then $U^{\bot\bot}=U$.